# Getting clicked button values jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find clicked button value.here is my htmlcode,I am  not able to get but always getting first one.

```
<div id="addSentiment" class="dialogs">
    <div id="1" class="dialogs">
        <div class="itemdiv dialogdiv">
            <div class="user">
                <img src="assets/avatars/avatar1.png" alt="Alexas Avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div class="time">  <i class="ace-icon fa fa-clock-o"></i>
    <span class="green">Date : 10/01/2014</span>

                </div>
                <div class="name">  <a href="index.html#">ki@n.com</a>

                </div>
                <div id="cat_1" class="text">category : Scheduling
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div id="op_1" class="text">ddd word/phrase : providing solutions
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div id="feature_1" class="text">ddd word/phrase : listen to
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="hd">
                </div>
                <div class="tools"> <a id="edit_1" class="btn acebtn btn-minier btn-info" href="#">
                                                                            <i class="icon-only ace-icon fa fa-share"></i>
                                                                        </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="dialogs">
        <div class="itemdiv dialogdiv">
            <div class="user">
                <img src="assets/avatars/avatar1.png" alt="Alexas Avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div class="time">  <i class="ace-icon fa fa-clock-o"></i>
    <span class="green">Date : 10/01/2014</span>

                </div>
                <div class="name">  <a href="index.html#">tc@n.com</a>

                </div>
                <div id="cat_2" class="text">category : Scheduling
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div id="op_2" class="text">dddd : providing solutions
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div id="feature_2" class="text">ddddddde : listen to
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="hd">
                </div>
                <div class="tools"> <a id="edit_2" class="btn acebtn btn-minier btn-info" href="#">
                                                                            <i class="icon-only ace-icon fa fa-share"></i>
                                                                        </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="3" class="dialogs">
        <div class="itemdiv dialogdiv">
            <div class="user">
                <img src="assets/avatars/avatar1.png" alt="Alexas Avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div class="time">  <i class="ace-icon fa fa-clock-o"></i>
    <span class="green">Date : 10/01/2014</span>

                </div>
                <div class="name">  <a href="index.html#">tn@nn.com</a>

                </div>
                <div id="cat_3" class="text">category : Scheduling
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div id="op_3" class="text">Opinion word/phrase : providing solutions
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div id="feature_3" class="text">Feature word/phrase : listen to
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="hd">
                </div>
                <div class="tools"> <a id="edit_3" class="btn acebtn btn-minier btn-info" href="#">
                                                                            <i class="icon-only ace-icon fa fa-share"></i>
                                                                        </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried following code in jquery

```
$(".dialogs .itemdiv .tools").live("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
alert('clicked on edit');

var n = $('.dialogs .itemdiv .tools a').attr('id');
    alert(n);
});
```

I use live here because I am getting above html by using append method in jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`live` is deprecated in later versions of jQuery - but to solve your issue you need to use an instance of `this`

```
$("#addSentiment").on("click", ".dialogs .itemdiv .tools", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked on edit');

    var n = $("a", this).attr('id');
    alert(n);
});
```

Comment: you have mentioned not to use live but I am getting only by using live.I tired 'on' but not getting so I used 'live'.

Comment: can you suggest alternative way.Because If we use append we don't get click event that is the main reason I used 'live'

Comment: `live` is deprecated: 1.7 | removed: 1.9 use delegate instead.

Comment: @aniltc -- I've edited the answer to work with `.on`

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery selectors** catch the first match of their content.

To catch the n-th match, you need to use the [n-th child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), like this:

```
$(".dialogs .itemdiv .tools:nth-child(2)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the live method, but you should be able to do something like the following:

```
function addHandlers() {
  $(".dialogs .itemdiv .tools a").each(function() {
     $(this).click(function() {
         alert('clicked on edit');
     );      
  });
}

function yourAppendFunction() {
   //your append code
   //add call to a function that will create your event handlers
   addHandlers();
}
```

The .each method runs through each and every item that fits the selection criteria, and then we use the this keyword within the function to reference what we are working on.  Putting it in a function that we don't call until after you append the items ensures the html exists when you try to add the handlers you need.

API references:

each method: http://api.jquery.com/each/

click method: http://api.jquery.com/click/